# Separating a comma separated string to a new table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I inherited a project that has comma separated strings stored in a field called '**subsector**' in a table named '**com_barchan_project**'. I need to change this horrible design, since it's proving to be an issue trying to parse through this field.  See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44008546/sql-query-to-match-a-comma-separated-string-against-a-comma-separated-string) for the full story:

```
| id | name | sector | subsector |
+----+------+--------+-----------+
|  1 | test |   2    |  3,4,7    |
+----+------+--------+-----------+
|  2 | door |   5    |  2        |
```

I have created a new table called '**com_barchan_project_subsector_join**' with the required fields and would like to move the values stored in '**com_barchan_project**' to this new empty table.

Can anyone help me with the SQL statement that would accomplish this?

Here's what the new '**com_barchan_project_subsector_join**' table should look like:

```
| id | project_id | subsector_id |
+----+------------+--------------+
|  1 |      1     |      3       |
+----+------------+--------------+
|  2 |      1     |      4       |
+----+------------+--------------+
|  3 |      1     |      7       |
+----+------------+--------------+
|  4 |      2     |      2       |
```

Once I move over the data, I will remove the 'subsector' field from the '**com_barchan_project**' table and be done with it.

Thanks for your help!!!

John

Comment: Senior Web Developer... really?

Comment: Senior Web Developer doesn't mean I have all the answers.  I'm not afraid to admit that this is not something I've had to do.  Why the need to insult.  Wow!  Rude.

Comment: you should approach this problem server side .. using  a procedural approach  (not relational  ... alias mysql based)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936088/mysql-split-comma-separated-list-into-multiple-rows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232800/how-to-split-up-a-comma-separated-table-into-multiple-rows-using-mysql

Comment: @Lashane:  Thanks for the links.  I looked at these, but they were not helpful in my case.  Uueerdo had the correct solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using shorter table names for brevity/clarity; and assuming you have (or can easily make) a comprehensive subsectors table...and assuming your csv are stored in a consistent format (no spaces at least).

```
INSERT INTO `project_subsectors` (project_id, subsector_id)
SELECT p.id, s.id
FROM projects AS p
INNER JOIN subsectors AS s ON p.subsector = s.id
                           OR p.subsector LIKE CONCAT(s.id, ',%')
                           OR p.subsector LIKE CONCAT('%,', s.id, ',%')
                           OR p.subsector LIKE CONCAT('%,', s.id)
;
```

I can't guarantee it will be fast; I'd be surprised if it was.

`ON FIND_IN_SET(s.id, p.subsector) > 0` may work as well, but I am not as familiar with the behavior of that function.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Your answer helped me get there.

Comment: @Ueerdo: By the way, it was fast.

Comment: @JohnLeger Was it a small table, or perhaps most rows only had single values in the field? _Join conditions with `OR` are usually relatively slow even without the overhead of LIKE comparisons and CONCAT() function calls._

Comment: There were about 800+ rows.  I only needed